# Is a truly nonsensical grammatically correct sentence possible?

Tags: english

Most "nonsensical" or "meaningless" sentences can be interpreted to mean *something* that isn't total nonsense:

- Colorless green ideas sleep furiously: "Nondescript immature ideas have violent nightmares"; "Naive ideas which have not yet attained their full scope can cause a mind to race even while it attempts to rest"; "Nondescript ideas for helping the environment are not being practically applied but are being rapidly developed"

Are there any grammatically correct sentences that have no possible interpretation?

Comment: Maybe by mixing terms from different scientific fields? "The wavelength of the virus accelerates genetically, although its checksum is planetary" seems to be truly meaningless.

Comment: Is an idea having a violent nightmare really meaningful? Your other two examples aren't meant as nonsensical sentences, but to show how many times an English word can be repeated and still produce a grammatically-correct result.

Comment: Of course, if you allow fake words, it's trivial. "Falsof dromels gree karethly" is grammatically valid if you say "falsof" is an adjective, "dromel" is a noun, "gree" is a verb, and "karethly" is an adverb.

Comment: Maybe a violent nightmare is a nightmare containing violence?

Comment: I just realized I misread your comment and your point was about an idea having a nightmare, not about a nightmare being violent.

Comment: A violent nightmare is fine, I question an idea having one. Ideas, lacking physical substance, cannot sleep or dream. I'd also remove the other two examples, since they're not intended to be meaningless.

Comment: @Draconis Sleeping furiously can be thought of as having a disturbed or restless sleep. "Green ideas" could easily be the ideas of  environmentalists for example. "Colourless" could mean non-racist or boring or an idea that hadn't been assigned a colour in some kind of ranking or assessment. An idea "sleeping furiously" might be an idea that has been out of the mainstream but is still activel supported and promoted by marginalised activists. Or many other interpretations.

Comment: I really do not understand why this question has got such a negative reaction. I'm completely baffled. Perhaps some downvoters and close voters could enlighten us?

Comment: I voted down because it is unclear that the suggested meanings are sensible, good-faith interpretations of the original sentence. So the premise of the question is doubtful.

Comment: Whybwouldbthebinterpretation have to be in good-faith? If somebody slips a freudian I will make sure to expound on that because I'm hostile, for the sake of the argument, and because I in turn doubt the verasity of the claim in

Comment: @Keelan Is that not rather a strange way of looking at it? Most linguists who deal in meaning would agree that sentences *have* no meaning untill used an actual utterance (including a written text) by a speaker who has a communicative intention. As Chomsky's example is not used as a communicative act but merely cited, maybe it's unreasonable to expect a listener/reader to give it a good faith interpretation. How can a listener give a good faith interpretation of the communicative intention of a speaker who does not exist? Especially in a context that does not exist?.

Comment: @Keelan Surely if any fault for disingenuity exists here it is with the original author and the fact that this is not well thought through. The OP's point here, which is surely a correct one, is that when listeners hear utterances used as part of communicative exchanges, they assume that the speaker has a communicative intention and will apply whatever resources they can to arrive at a meaningful interpretation. Chomsky's point would only ever be worth anything if absolutely no interpretation of the sentence could be a natural interpretation in any context. But this is not the case.

Comment: @Araucaria-him but then the question should be whether there are sentences which are not natural in any context. In my view, the question has it backwards in assuming that such a context existed because the sentence was uttered, and then trying to recover the meaning. It seems to me the more useful approach would be to ask whether sentences like the example can ever be produced in good faith. And I would never utter the example in the contexts suggested by the suggested "meanings", so I doubt the premise of the question.

Comment: That you can provide synonyms and periphrases for the parts doesn't mean the whole sentence (or the outputs of such operations) has any actual sense or reference. It only proves that you know the definitions of the parts and some rules of combination. The sentence grinds to a halt at "colourless green", actually, the rest being redundant on top of that contradiction -- and it hardly matters whether it's green or blue, colourless or achromatic, the combination is undefinable both in sense and reference.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Colours are regularly used metaphorically, perhaps more often than with their narrowest literal sense. So having two colour adjectives which would be contradictory if I used to refer to colours happens all the time. And if a brain can wring a meaning out of an utterance, it will!

Answer (score 3):

Strings of sound can be given an interpretation in at least two ways. The usual method, whereby we typically define "possible interpretation", is "strictly using the rules of the grammar in this language". Another method – the one typically used by the overwhelming majority of humans – is "using any and all evidence and methods available". The latter method is extremely useful when called on by individuals attempting to communicate, who do not have a common language: it allows one to be understood, even when you massively violate the rules of grammar.

There are many pre-compiled strings that are used in language differently from what you would expect given literal semantics, for example "pot calling the kettle black" is literally an absurdity. Moreover, the actual interpretation of the utterance cannot be related by rule to word meaning and principles of compositional semantics.

The answer to your question depends on having an explicit theory of lexical meaning, syntax, and semantic composition. It presupposes that syntactic distribution is blind to semantic properties – a possible but not logically-necessary position. All attempts that I am aware of to compose the meaning of strings from the meaning of the components (including abstract "thematic role" marking) are very general – they say that you can can combine "P", "x" and "y" to derive the proposition "P(x,y)" as well as "P(y,x)". In such compositional theories, all well-formed sentences have a semantic interpretation. But: not all such propositions describe actually-possible states of affairs. Avicenna's defense of the law of non-contradiction ("Those who deny the first principle should be flogged or burned until they admit that it is not the same thing to be burned and not burned, or whipped and not whipped") reminds us that we can conceptualize things that do not exist, and that contradict the nature of the universe.

In other words, it depends on what you mean by "mean". If you think meaning is about actual states of affairs in the real world, then it's easy to construct grammatically well-formed strings that have no meaning because they don't describe facts. I just think that is the wrong theory of meaning.

Comment: Given the absolute kicking this question has undeservedly received, I think your answer could be more helpfully be framed as supportive from the outset. It was only when I got to the last paragraph that I realised its thrust (I thought it was heading in the other direction). Based solely on projecting my own laziness onto other users here, many might not get to your last paragraph, skim your answer and completely misunderstand your meaning.

Comment: Maybe a meaningless sentence is one in which there are no grammatical relationships between words that have any significance in that context? In that case, my example of "The wavelength of the virus accelerates genetically, although its checksum is planetary" is completely meaningless, because viruses don't have wavelengths, a wavelength can't accelerate, genetics and acceleration are unrelated, wavelengths don't have checksums (a particular representation of a wavelength might, but the length itself doesn't), and checksums have nothing to do with planets.

Answer (score 1):

The entire poem Jaberwocky (sp) is completely nonsensical, but completely grammatically correct.

Comment: Yes, but it uses a lot of non-words.

Answer (score 0):

Russels paradox or the liar's paradox are statements known to have no logical truth value. A naive example:

> This sentence is false.

Depending on how you define *meaning* and *truth*, this sentence can be argued to be meaningless. It is nevertheless a meaningful example. If your flavor of logic is chosen appropriately, we can show that the statement is simply wrong without at the same time implying that its opposite were true.

Also, this depends on your definition of grammaticality. The Chomskian colorful green idea does challenge this concept and still depends on a empirical validition. I.e. a construct is **ungrammatical if speakers of nominal Language reject it**. Showing that it is accepted by a significant share of the population - again to be defined arbitrarily - would be a different problem.

Russels Paradox is older than that, applied to *naive set theory*. Meanwhile, homotopy type theory and other modern extensions of the classical concept may allow it in higher orders of logic, which can be projected via schema of induction in first order logic.

Comment: _This sentence is true_ is equally meaningless, but logically spotless. Which is an example of why logic is a weak reed to lean on.

Comment: It isn't spotless, because it defines itself as a sentence and, in this context, also defines "sentence" at the same time. It's Russel's paradox in effect. For sake of the argument I might not be able to accomodate your definition. This may be a slippery sloap or classical circular reasoning abiut a fix point. Critically, "truth" is not mathematically defined (cf. foundational crisis in mathematics), but they still produce result. ... Or do you mean a form of *point-free* logic?